# Android: aling background of setPageMarginDrawable to fit into margin

Tags: android, alignment

I have a ViewPager with a graphic in between:

```
mPager.setPageMarginDrawable(R.drawable.margin);
```

I have set the image to repeat in y direction.

margin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:dither="true" />
```

The problem is that it does not align to margin space. It seems that its repeated independently of the size of the ViewPager. On one device I mangaged to get the size that it fits into because its a multiple of the screen width in landscape and portraint, but on other devices it wont work.
Is there a solution for my problem?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay solved it my own. 
I scale the margin drawable programatically so that the display width is a multiple of it. 
not beautiful, but working. better solutins are welcome.